# Global variable in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe issue ( little bit strange for me ) . The issue is that i have an iframe in my document, and there are several functions are operating different task on that iframe and for accessing the contents of iframe we use :

```
$("iframe").contents();
```

So instead of writing this long statement i used a global variable :

```
var i = $("iframe").contents();
```

But this is not working well, like

```
alert( i.find("someelement") );
```

=> `undefined`

```
alert($("iframe").contents().find("someelement")
```

=> `[object]`

Whats the problem here?

Comment: paste your complete code like where have you declared i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var i = $("iframe").contents();
```

with

```
window.i = $("iframe").contents();
```

As `i` has a lesser scope than `window`, which is used to declare global variables in JavaScript.

But one more thing is, you cannot modify any items inside the `iframe`, if it is from a different domain. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overwriting `i` somewhere, or it's not global. To ensure it's global, don't use var. Instead, define `window.i = ...;` and always refer to `window.i`. This avoids possible confusion with a local variable (which can happen quite often given that `i` is almost always used as an iterator variable). Also make extra sure you always declare `i` as local if you're using it for anything but the iframe (such as the aforementioned iterator).

Answer (score 0):

Is the content of your iframe on the same domain as the page where it is interted ?

More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy